# Retrieve user defined properties (for Outlook emails) using Graph API

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am working on an add-in for Outlook for Web using the [Office JavaScript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview?view=outlook-js-preview). A requirement in my project is to read/update an existing User-Defined Property on emails. This property is needed by a legacy add-in for the desktop version of Outlook.

In the Outlook for Web add-in, I would like to be able to retrieve and update this User-Defined Property. Is there an API I can use that will support this functionality?

Additionally, I've had a look at Open and Schema Extension Properties in the Graph API, but I don't think these relate to the User-Defined Property, and I'm a bit confused.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more details on what do you mean by User-Defined Property. Are you talking about Custom Properties? Also, if you want to set a key-value pair on an email that you want to retrieve later, you can make use of internet headers or custom properties.

Comment: We have a legacy add-in that uses the Interop API to set custom properties on emails. They appear in the "user-defined fields in folder" if you add an advanced filter to a view in Outlook desktop. I need to access these properties in Outlook for Web add-in. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.userproperties?view=outlook-pia

Comment: Do you have access to modify both the add-ins? Can you use internet headers instead of custom properties as they will be available across all platforms?